# Update one Fragment due to changes in another fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

#### The Scenario:

I have two fragments(each in a separate tab) doing work that's related to each other. For example:

```
public class A extends Fragment{
// Take user input and calculate a geo-location(this works fine)
// User can also mannually enter a location address and the geocoder
// figures out the Lat/Lng of that location.
// Uses a Asych task.
}

public class B extends Fragment{
// This a Google map. Based on Latitude & Longitude
// place a marker at that location(which is provided by class A.)
// Do other Stuff aswell 
}
```

#### The problem:

I want to pass the location information to Class B. However I am having trouble with updating the map with the marker once I am finished calculating my location in class A.
What I have seen is that the minute my app starts the class B onCreateView() method runs. This is where I would normally put my Marker functions information. However the Asych task from Class A takes some time to calculate the geolocation and therefore I don't have a Location to provide to the markers method in class B just yet. Is there anyway to add the marker to the map once the Asych task has completed without calling onCreateView() (for Class B) in class A again?

---

#### In other words

Can I somehow pass the Location information (for the markers method) and therefore drop a marker on the google map once my Asych task has completed.

Comment: You can use Local Broadcast Receiver

Comment: there is a third party library called eventbus.You can use interface as a call back to the activity and then communicate to Fragment B

Comment: Check this http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html. You have a example.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to communicate between fragments is using listeners , here you can find  [an example how to implement that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15447804/fragment-fragment-communication-in-android)

When your AsyncTask ends you can call your listener which will communicate with your FragmentB and add the marker in map

Answer (score 0):

Pass the reference of your `Fragment B` to `Fragment A` constructor.

You can then create a method in `Fragment B` that adds the `marker` to the Map.

In `Fragment A` after the marker location is downloaded you can then call the reference of `Fragment B` and call its `method` to update the marker

Comment: wrong constructor for a Fragment??. Fragments should have no arg constructor

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html. See the third paragraph. First line

Comment: @Raghunandan, yup you are absolutely right Fragment constructors should not have arguments. There is no easy way to go around this problem the way I look at it

Comment: @Raghunandan just saying that he can use the reference of Fragment to get the marker, and yes there is a lot of option such as callbacks

Comment: @SeahawksRdaBest well you have options you can use interface as a callback to the activity and then communicate to fragment B or EventBus which is a third party library. What do you mean by easy option. For the first there is example in the docs. For the second read the eventbus page on github

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin Fragment should have no-arg constructor. So how will you get the fragment A reference in fragment B. Fragment A --> Activity --> Fragment B. use interface as a call back

Comment: @Raghunandan, i kind of get what you are saying. Can you give me some Pseudo code? So I can understand your idea completely?

Comment: @SeahawksRdaBest you can go here to learn about callback http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html