# How to update TextView in a fragment when exiting from another fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

So I have a fragment A which has a button to open another a fragment B. In fragment B I can pick some options, which is bundled into an `Bundle`object. When I exit from fragment B, I want to refresh a TextView in fragment A.

Right now I'm using `dismiss()` method to remove the fragment, and then call back the fragment again so that `onCreateView()` is called. It works fine, but I don't want the animation where the fragment windows is run. So I like to not use `dismiss()` to remove the fragment instead I want to keep it on the Activity, but I need to know how I can refresh fragment A. I've tried overriding `onActivityCreated()` but it didn't result in the action I wanted.

So I wonder what's the approach if I want to refresh fragment A without having to dismiss it first so that `onCreateView()` can be called again.

I can attach code if needed. But maybe just an explanation is enough here?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: @Raghunandan that one seems only to explain how you communicate to a fragment from e.g `MainActivity()`

Comment: that explains how to use interface a callback to the activity. Then it explains how you communicate from activity to fragment. Which is what you want right?

Comment: I want to pass data from fragment B to fragment A. A `TextView` in fragment A will then be updated. Both fragments extends the `DialogFragment` class. So it is not exactly communcation from activity to fragment. At least as what I understand it is.

Comment: you haven't read the link properly. read it again. Fragment B -->Activity -->Fragment A

Comment: ah yes you are right. I skimmed through it too fast ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the life cycle function onResume() in fragment A to update the textview.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own Listener interface ( [example how to do it](http://tseng-blog.nge-web.net/blog/2009/02/17/how-implement-your-own-listener-android-java/)  or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15447804/fragment-fragment-communication-in-android)) that listens when you remove your fragment, and you can get the event on Fragment A where you can setText to your TextView.