# Communicating between the tablayout Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-tablayout

I used a tab layout with fragment. The scenario goes like this.

Activity:

Fragment 1 , Fragment2 , Fragment3

From Fragment2 Updating the UI of Fragment1.

I tried to access the methods from fragment but resulting **null pointer exception**.

Comment: So where is code so we can check where is null exception?

Comment: @Piyush lost the code while trying different approaches. In general to achieve this what is best practice

Comment: [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15448538/8470296)

Comment: plz provide your code structure then i will find your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You may use `Observer Pattern` to achieve this. To do this, You have to  create a `MutableLiveData` in your `MainActivity` and pass it to `fragment` through `interface`.
2. Then post value from **FragmentA** and observe it from **FragmentB** and do operation when change

Create interface:

```
interface UpdateFragmentListener {
    fun onUpdate(): MutableLiveData<Any>
}
```

Implements this in `Activity`:

```
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity, UpdateFragmentListener {
   val fragmentUpdate: MutableLiveData<Any> = MutableLiveData()

   ...

   override fun onUpdate(): MutableLiveData<Any> = fragmentUpdate
}
```

Inside FragmentA:

...

```
val updateListener: UpdateFragmentListener 

override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    updateListener = context as UpdateFragmentListener 
}

override fun onViewCreated(v: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle) { 
    super.onViewCreated(v, savedInstanceState

    //use like this by modifying it wherever you need inside FragmentA
    updateListener.onUpdate().postValue(Any())

}
```

Inside FragmentB:

...

```
val updateListener: UpdateFragmentListener 

override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    updateListener = context as UpdateFragmentListener 
}

override fun onViewCreated(v: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle) { 
    super.onViewCreated(v, savedInstanceState

    //Observe it and do operation wherever you need inside FragmentB
    updateListener.onUpdate().observe(this, Observer { 
        // implement your logic here
    })

}
```