# How to replace a fragment with another fragment with a web view to open different URLs by clicking on different items in the recyclerview?

Tags: android

My problem is, I have a recyclerview implemented in a fragment called "FragmentNewsItems" that lists out the set of news (images + text) in cardview. So my task is, to make the app, so that when I click on one of those items in the recyclerview, the app would replace it with another fragment with a web view.

Some good people advised me to create a click event:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

// add this line
private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
            private ImageView image;
            private TextView text;
            FragmentNewsItems fragmentNewsItems = new FragmentNewsItems();


            public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
                text = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);

                itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            }

      @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mAdapter.onItemHolderClick(ViewHolder.this);
            }

        }

        public void setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
            this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
        }

        private void onItemHolderClick(ViewHolder holder) {
            if (onItemClickListener != null)
                onItemClickListener.onItemClick(null, holder.itemView, holder.getAdapterPosition(), holder.getItemId());
        }
}
```

and then add the click event to the fragment:

```
public class FragmentNewsItems extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{


View view;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private List<NewsItems> cyberNews;
    private FragmentNewsItems fragmentNewsItems;

    public FragmentNewsItems(){
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.f_news_items_layout, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.news_items_recycler_view);

        RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getContext(), cyberNews);
// add this line
recyclerAdapter .setOnItemClickListener(this);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        cyberNews = new ArrayList<>();
        cyberNews.add(new NewsItems(R.drawable.cyber1, "The  of cybersecurity in 5G-connected world"));
        cyberNews.add(new NewsItems(R.drawable.cyber2, "Google discovered several iPhone security flaws, and Apple still hasn't patched one"));
        cyberNews.add(new NewsItems(R.drawable.cyber3, "WhatsApp and Telegram media files aren't so secure"));
        cyberNews.add(new NewsItems(R.drawable.cyber4, "Microsoft Exposes Russian Cyberattacks on Phones, Printers, Video Decoders"));
        cyberNews.add(new NewsItems(R.drawable.cyber5, "Tesla demonstrated the power of The Internet of Things"));

    }


@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
// here open new activity or replace fragment which have webview.
}
```

Like this:

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
// here open new activity or replace fragment which have webview.
}
```

But you see a comment which says open a new activity or replace fragment which have a webview. I tried multiple times to replace with another fragment, but it simply does not open my fragment. I mean, it loads the layout, but does not replace with another fragment. I am a new to Android, and to be honest I have no idea what's wrong. Can you help me with coding?

Comment: add your main activity too, it'll be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

create a new fragment for web view and pass your data and replace new fragment using your activity:

check my answer for this question:

> [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58680300](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58680300/how-can-i-pass-a-string-between-fragments/58680731#58680731)