# NullPointerException in fragment to fragment Communication Adding data in ListView

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I have a method inside a "FragmentA" and I want to trigger that method when I click the button from the "FragmentB". But it throws a NullPointerException.

This is the method I want to call from FragmentA

```
public void getdefaultvaluestoprint()
    {
        this.sqLiteDatabase = this.db.getWritableDatabase();
        this.cursor = this.sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("select c.account_no, c.name, c.address, c.meter_number, c.multiplier, c.type, " +
                "c.year_bill, c.month_bill, " +
                "c.date, c.present_reading, r.gen_system_charge, r.trans_system_chg," +
                "r.system_loss_chg, r.distr_system_chg, r.supply_system_chg, r.supply_retail_chg, " +
                "r.meter_system_chg, r.meter_retail_chg, r.rsfc, r.life_line_subsidy, r.ppa_refund, " +
                "r.iccs_adjustment, r.generation_vat, r.transmission_vat, r.system_loss_vat, r.distribution_vat, r.others_vat, r.senior_citizen_subsidy, " +
                "r.fit_all, r.missionary_elec_spug, r.envir_charge," +
                "r.stranded_contract_cost, r.npc_scc_debt from Consumer as c, Rate as r on substr(r.type,1,1) = c.type where " +
                "c.account_no = '101090316'", null);
        this.toprintdefaultvalueaccount.clear();
        this.toprintdefaultvaluename.clear();
        this.toprintdefaultvalueaddress.clear();
        this.toprintdefaultvaluemeter_number.clear();
        this.toprintdefaultvaluemultiplier.clear();
        this.toprintdefaultvaluetype.clear();
        this.toprintdefaultvaluebilling_period_year.clear();
        this.toprintdefaultvaluebilling_period_month.clear();
        this.toprintdefaultvaluelast_reading.clear();
        this.toprintdefaultvaluelast_date_record.clear();
        this.toprintdefaultvaluegen_system_charge.clear();
        this.toprintdefaultvaluetrans_system_chg.clear();
        this.toprintdefaultvaluesystem_loss_chg.clear();
        this.toprintdefaultvaluedistr_system_chg.clear();
        this.toprintdefaultvaluesupply_system_chg.clear();
        this.toprintdefaultvaluesupply_retail_chg.clear();
        this.toprintdefaultvaluemeter_system_chg.clear();
        this.toprintdefaultvaluemeter_retail_chg.clear();
        this.toprintdefaultvaluersfc.clear();
        this.toprintdefaultvaluelife_line_subsidy.clear();
        this.toprintdefaultvalueppa_refund.clear();
        this.toprintdefaultvalueiccs_adjustment.clear();
        this.toprintdefaultvaluegeneration_vat.clear();
        this.toprintdefaultvaluetransmission_vat.clear();
        this.toprintdefaultvaluesystem_loss_vat.clear();
        this.toprintdefaultvaluedistribution_vat.clear();
        this.toprintdefaultvalueothers_vat.clear();
        this.toprintdefaultvaluesenior_citizen_subsidy.clear();
        this.toprintdefaultvaluefit_all.clear();
        this.toprintdefaultvaluemissionary_elec_spug.clear();
        this.toprintdefaultvalueenvir_charge.clear();
        this.toprintdefaultvaluestranded_contract_cost.clear();
        this.toprintdefaultvaluenpc_scc_debt.clear();

        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {           
             this.toprintdefaultvalueaccount.add(this.cursor.getString(this.cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("account_no")));
                this.toprintdefaultvaluename.add(this.cursor.getString(this.cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("name")));
                this.toprintdefaultvalueaddress.add(this.cursor.getString(this.cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")));
                this.toprintdefaultvaluemeter_number.add(this.cursor.getString(this.cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("meter_number")));
                this.toprintdefaultvaluemultiplier.add(this.cursor.getString(this.cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("multiplier")));
                this.toprintdefaultvaluetype.add(this.cursor.getString(this.cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("type")));

this.toprintdefaultvaluebilling_period_year.add(this.cursor.getString(this.cursor.getColumnIndex("year_bill")));
                this.toprintdefaultvaluebilling_period_month.add(this.cursor.getString(this.cursor.getColumnIndex("month_bill")));
                this.toprintdefaultvaluelast_reading.add(this.cursor.getString(this.cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("present_reading")));
                this.toprintdefaultvaluelast_date_record.add(this.cursor.getString(this.cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date")));
                this.toprintdefaultvaluegen_system_charge.add(this.cursor.getString(this.cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("gen_system_charge")));
                this.toprintdefaultvaluetrans_system_chg.add(this.cursor.getString(this.cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("trans_system_chg")));
                this.toprintdefaultvaluesystem_loss_chg.add(this.cursor.getString(this.cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("system_loss_chg")));
                this.toprintdefaultvaluedistr_system_chg.add(this.cursor.getString(this.cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("distr_system_chg")));
                this.toprintdefaultvaluesupply_system_chg.add(this.cursor.getString(this.cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("supply_system_chg")));
                this.toprintdefaultvaluesupply_retail_chg.add(this.cursor.getString(this.cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("supply_retail_chg")));
                this.toprintdefaultvaluemeter_system_chg.add(this.cursor.getString(this.cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("meter_system_chg")));
                this.toprintdefaultvaluemeter_retail_chg.add(this.cursor.getString(this.cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("meter_retail_chg")));
                this.toprintdefaultvaluersfc.add(this.cursor.getString(this.cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("rsfc")));
                this.toprintdefaultvaluelife_line_subsidy.add(this.cursor.getString(this.cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("life_line_subsidy")));
                this.toprintdefaultvalueppa_refund.add(this.cursor.getString(this.cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ppa_refund")));
                this.toprintdefaultvalueiccs_adjustment.add(this.cursor.getString(this.cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("iccs_adjustment")));
                this.toprintdefaultvaluegeneration_vat.add(this.cursor.getString(this.cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("generation_vat")));
                this.toprintdefaultvaluetransmission_vat.add(this.cursor.getString(this.cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("transmission_vat")));
                this.toprintdefaultvaluesystem_loss_vat.add(this.cursor.getString(this.cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("system_loss_vat")));
                this.toprintdefaultvaluedistribution_vat.add(this.cursor.getString(this.cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("distribution_vat")));
                this.toprintdefaultvalueothers_vat.add(this.cursor.getString(this.cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("others_vat")));
                this.toprintdefaultvaluesenior_citizen_subsidy.add(this.cursor.getString(this.cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("senior_citizen_subsidy")));
                this.toprintdefaultvaluefit_all.add(this.cursor.getString(this.cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("fit_all")));
                this.toprintdefaultvaluemissionary_elec_spug.add(this.cursor.getString(this.cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("missionary_elec_spug")));
                this.toprintdefaultvalueenvir_charge.add(this.cursor.getString(this.cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("envir_charge")));
                this.toprintdefaultvaluestranded_contract_cost.add(this.cursor.getString(this.cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("stranded_contract_cost")));
                this.toprintdefaultvaluenpc_scc_debt.add(this.cursor.getString(this.cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("npc_scc_debt")));
            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext());
      }

        toprintdefaultadapter = new com.vicjames.finalmeterreader.adapters.toprintAdapter
                (getActivity(),
                        this.toprintdefaultvalueaccount,
                        this.toprintdefaultvaluename,
                        this.toprintdefaultvalueaddress,
                        this.toprintdefaultvaluemeter_number,
                        this.toprintdefaultvaluemultiplier,
                        this.toprintdefaultvaluetype,
                        this.toprintdefaultvaluebilling_period_year,
                        this.toprintdefaultvaluebilling_period_month,
                        this.toprintdefaultvaluelast_reading,
                        this.toprintdefaultvaluelast_date_record,
                        this.toprintdefaultvaluegen_system_charge,
                        this.toprintdefaultvaluetrans_system_chg,
                        this.toprintdefaultvaluesystem_loss_chg,
                        this.toprintdefaultvaluedistr_system_chg,
                        this.toprintdefaultvaluesupply_system_chg,
                        this.toprintdefaultvaluesupply_retail_chg,
                        this.toprintdefaultvaluemeter_system_chg,
                        this.toprintdefaultvaluemeter_retail_chg,
                        this.toprintdefaultvaluersfc,
                        this.toprintdefaultvaluelife_line_subsidy,
                        this.toprintdefaultvalueppa_refund,
                        this.toprintdefaultvalueiccs_adjustment,
                        this.toprintdefaultvaluegeneration_vat,
                        this.toprintdefaultvaluetransmission_vat,
                        this.toprintdefaultvaluesystem_loss_vat,
                        this.toprintdefaultvaluedistribution_vat,
                        this.toprintdefaultvalueothers_vat,
                        this.toprintdefaultvaluesenior_citizen_subsidy,
                        this.toprintdefaultvaluefit_all,
                        this.toprintdefaultvaluemissionary_elec_spug,
                        this.toprintdefaultvalueenvir_charge,
                        this.toprintdefaultvaluestranded_contract_cost,
                        this.toprintdefaultvaluenpc_scc_debt);
        toprintlist.setAdapter(toprintdefaultadapter);
        cursor.close();
    }
```

This is the on click listener which is in the FragmentB

```
private Button btnsavenewreading;


public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        homeViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

btnsavenewreading = root.findViewById(R.id.btnsave);
btnsavenewreading.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) throws  NullPointerException
            {             
                FragmentManager toprintdefault = getFragmentManager();
                ToolsFragment toolsFragment = (ToolsFragment)toprintdefault.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_toolsx);
                toolsFragment.getdefaultvaluestoprint();
            }

        });
return root;
}
```

This is the adapter code

```
public class toprintAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
        Context context;
        ArrayList<String> account;
        ArrayList<String> name;
        ArrayList<String> address;
        ArrayList<String> meter_number;
        ArrayList<String> multiplier;
        ArrayList<String> type;
        ArrayList<String> billing_period_year;
        ArrayList<String> billing_period_month;
        ArrayList<String> last_reading;
        ArrayList<String> last_date_record;
        ArrayList<String> gen_system_charge;
        ArrayList<String> trans_system_chg;
        ArrayList<String> system_loss_chg;
        ArrayList<String> distr_system_chg;
        ArrayList<String> supply_system_chg;
        ArrayList<String> supply_retail_chg;
        ArrayList<String> meter_system_chg;
        ArrayList<String> meter_retail_chg;
        ArrayList<String> rsfc;
        ArrayList<String> life_line_subsidy;
        ArrayList<String> ppa_refund;
        ArrayList<String> iccs_adjustment;
        ArrayList<String> generation_vat;
        ArrayList<String> transmission_vat;
        ArrayList<String> system_loss_vat;
        ArrayList<String> distribution_vat;
        ArrayList<String> others_vat;
        ArrayList<String> senior_citizen_subsidy;
        ArrayList<String> fit_all;
        ArrayList<String> missionary_elec_spug;
        ArrayList<String> envir_charge;
        ArrayList<String> stranded_contract_cost;
        ArrayList<String> npc_scc_debt;

        public toprintAdapter(Context context2, ArrayList<String> account, ArrayList<String> name, ArrayList<String> address,
                              ArrayList<String> meter_number, ArrayList<String> multiplier, ArrayList<String> type,
                              ArrayList<String> billing_period_year, ArrayList<String> billing_period_month, ArrayList<String> last_reading, ArrayList<String> last_date_record,
                              ArrayList<String> gen_system_charge, ArrayList<String> trans_system_chg, ArrayList<String> system_loss_chg,
                              ArrayList<String> distr_system_chg, ArrayList<String> supply_system_chg, ArrayList<String> supply_retail_chg,
                              ArrayList<String> meter_system_chg, ArrayList<String> meter_retail_chg, ArrayList<String> rsfc,
                              ArrayList<String> life_line_subsidy, ArrayList<String> ppa_refund, ArrayList<String> iccs_adjustment,
                              ArrayList<String> generation_vat, ArrayList<String> transmission_vat, ArrayList<String> system_loss_vat,
                              ArrayList<String> distribution_vat, ArrayList<String> others_vat, ArrayList<String> senior_citizen_subsidy,
                              ArrayList<String> fit_all, ArrayList<String> missionary_elec_spug, ArrayList<String> envir_charge,
                              ArrayList<String> stranded_contract_cost, ArrayList<String> npc_scc_debt)
        {
                this.context = context2;
                this.account = account;
                this.name = name;
                this.address = address;
                this.meter_number = meter_number;
                this.multiplier = multiplier;
                this.type = type;
                this.billing_period_year = billing_period_year;
                this.billing_period_month = billing_period_month;
                this.last_reading = last_reading;
                this.last_date_record = last_date_record;
                this.gen_system_charge = gen_system_charge;
                this.trans_system_chg = trans_system_chg;
                this.system_loss_chg = system_loss_chg;
                this.distr_system_chg = distr_system_chg;
                this.supply_system_chg = supply_system_chg;
                this.supply_retail_chg = supply_retail_chg;
                this.meter_system_chg = meter_system_chg;
                this.meter_retail_chg = meter_retail_chg;
                this.rsfc = rsfc;
                this.life_line_subsidy = life_line_subsidy;
                this.ppa_refund = ppa_refund;
                this.iccs_adjustment = iccs_adjustment;
                this.generation_vat = generation_vat;
                this.transmission_vat = transmission_vat;
                this.system_loss_vat = system_loss_vat;
                this.distribution_vat = distribution_vat;
                this.others_vat = others_vat;
                this.senior_citizen_subsidy = senior_citizen_subsidy;
                this.fit_all = fit_all;
                this.missionary_elec_spug = missionary_elec_spug;
                this.envir_charge = envir_charge;
                this.stranded_contract_cost = stranded_contract_cost;
                this.npc_scc_debt = npc_scc_debt;
        }

        public int getCount()
        {
                return this.account.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position)
        {
                return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position)
        {
                return 0L;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View child, ViewGroup parent)
        {
                toprintAdapter.Holder holder;
                if (child == null)
                {
                        @SuppressLint("WrongConstant") LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService("layout_inflater");
                        child = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.meter_reading_to_print, null);
                        holder = new toprintAdapter.Holder();
                        holder.textprintdefaultaccount = child.findViewById(R.id.p_account_no);
                        holder.textprintdefaultname = child.findViewById(R.id.p_name);
                        holder.textprintdefaultaddress = child.findViewById(R.id.p_address);
                        holder.textprintdefaultmeter_number = child.findViewById(R.id.p_meter_number);
                        holder.textprintdefaultmultiplier = child.findViewById(R.id.p_multiplier);
                        holder.textprintdefaulttype = child.findViewById(R.id.p_type);
                        holder.textprintdefaultbilling_period_year = child.findViewById(R.id.p_billing_period_year);
                        holder.textprintdefaultbilling_period_month = child.findViewById(R.id.p_billing_period_month);
                        holder.textprintdefaultlast_reading = child.findViewById(R.id.p_last_reading);
                        holder.textprintdefaultlast_date_record = child.findViewById(R.id.p_last_record_date_reading);
                        holder.textprintdefaultgen_system_charge = child.findViewById(R.id.p_rate_gen_system_charge);
                        holder.textprintdefaulttrans_system_chg = child.findViewById(R.id.p_rate_trans_system_chg);
                        holder.textprintdefaultsystem_loss_chg = child.findViewById(R.id.p_rate_system_loss_chg);
                        holder.textprintdefaultdistr_system_chg = child.findViewById(R.id.p_rate_distr_system_chg);
                        holder.textprintdefaultsupply_system_chg = child.findViewById(R.id.p_rate_supply_system_chg);
                        holder.textprintdefaultsupply_retail_chg = child.findViewById(R.id.p_rate_supply_retail_chg);
                        holder.textprintdefaultmeter_system_chg = child.findViewById(R.id.p_rate_meter_system_chg);
                        holder.textprintdefaultmeter_retail_chg = child.findViewById(R.id.p_rate_meter_retail_chg);
                        holder.textprintdefaultrsfc = child.findViewById(R.id.p_rate_rsfc);
                        holder.textprintdefaultlife_line_subsidy = child.findViewById(R.id.p_rate_life_line_subsidy);
                        holder.textprintdefaultppa_refund = child.findViewById(R.id.p_rate_ppa_refund);
                        holder.textprintdefaulticcs_adjustment = child.findViewById(R.id.p_rate_iccs_adjsutment);
                        holder.textprintdefaultgeneration_vat = child.findViewById(R.id.p_rate_generation_vat);
                        holder.textprintdefaulttransmission_vat = child.findViewById(R.id.p_rate_transmission_vat);
                        holder.textprintdefaultsystem_loss_vat = child.findViewById(R.id.p_rate_system_loss_vat);
                        holder.textprintdefaultdistribution_vat = child.findViewById(R.id.p_rate_distribution_vat);
                        holder.textprintdefaultothers_vat = child.findViewById(R.id.p_rate_others_vat);
                        holder.textprintdefaultsenior_citizen_subsidy = child.findViewById(R.id.p_rate_senior_ctzn_subsidy);
                        holder.textprintdefaultfit_all = child.findViewById(R.id.p_rate_fit_all);
                        holder.textprintdefaultmissionary_elec_spug = child.findViewById(R.id.p_rate_missnry_elec_spug);
                        holder.textprintdefaultenvir_charge = child.findViewById(R.id.p_rate_envir_charge);
                        holder.textprintdefaultstranded_contract_cost = child.findViewById(R.id.p_rate_strndd_cntrct_cst);
                        holder.textprintdefaultnpc_scc_debt = child.findViewById(R.id.p_rate_npc_scc_debt);
                        child.setTag(holder);
                }
                else
                {
                        holder = (toprintAdapter.Holder)child.getTag();
                }
                holder.textprintdefaultaccount.setText(this.account.get(position));
                holder.textprintdefaultname.setText(this.name.get(position));
                holder.textprintdefaultaddress.setText(this.address.get(position));
                holder.textprintdefaultmeter_number.setText(this.meter_number.get(position));
                holder.textprintdefaultmultiplier.setText(this.multiplier.get(position));
                holder.textprintdefaulttype.setText(this.type.get(position));
                holder.textprintdefaultbilling_period_year.setText(this.billing_period_year.get(position));
                holder.textprintdefaultbilling_period_month.setText(this.billing_period_month.get(position));
                holder.textprintdefaultlast_reading.setText(this.last_reading.get(position));
                holder.textprintdefaultlast_date_record.setText(this.last_date_record.get(position));
                holder.textprintdefaultgen_system_charge.setText(this.gen_system_charge.get(position));
                holder.textprintdefaulttrans_system_chg.setText(this.trans_system_chg.get(position));
                holder.textprintdefaultsystem_loss_chg.setText(this.system_loss_chg.get(position));
                holder.textprintdefaultdistr_system_chg.setText(this.distr_system_chg.get(position));
                holder.textprintdefaultsupply_system_chg.setText(this.supply_system_chg.get(position));
                holder.textprintdefaultsupply_retail_chg.setText(this.supply_retail_chg.get(position));
                holder.textprintdefaultmeter_system_chg.setText(this.meter_system_chg.get(position));
                holder.textprintdefaultmeter_retail_chg.setText(this.meter_retail_chg.get(position));
                holder.textprintdefaultrsfc.setText(this.rsfc.get(position));
                holder.textprintdefaultlife_line_subsidy.setText(this.life_line_subsidy.get(position));
                holder.textprintdefaultppa_refund.setText(this.ppa_refund.get(position));
                holder.textprintdefaulticcs_adjustment.setText(this.iccs_adjustment.get(position));
                holder.textprintdefaultgeneration_vat.setText(this.generation_vat.get(position));
                holder.textprintdefaulttransmission_vat.setText(this.transmission_vat.get(position));
                holder.textprintdefaultsystem_loss_vat.setText(this.system_loss_vat.get(position));
                holder.textprintdefaultdistribution_vat.setText(this.distribution_vat.get(position));
                holder.textprintdefaultothers_vat.setText(this.others_vat.get(position));
                holder.textprintdefaultsenior_citizen_subsidy.setText(this.senior_citizen_subsidy.get(position));
                holder.textprintdefaultfit_all.setText(this.fit_all.get(position));
                holder.textprintdefaultmissionary_elec_spug.setText(this.missionary_elec_spug.get(position));
                holder.textprintdefaultenvir_charge.setText(this.envir_charge.get(position));
                holder.textprintdefaultstranded_contract_cost.setText(this.stranded_contract_cost.get(position));
                holder.textprintdefaultnpc_scc_debt.setText(this.npc_scc_debt.get(position));
                return child;
        }

        public class Holder
        {
                TextView textprintdefaultaccount;
                TextView textprintdefaultname;
                TextView textprintdefaultaddress;
                TextView textprintdefaultmeter_number;
                TextView textprintdefaultmultiplier;
                TextView textprintdefaulttype;
                TextView textprintdefaultbilling_period_year;
                TextView textprintdefaultbilling_period_month;
                TextView textprintdefaultlast_reading;
                TextView textprintdefaultlast_date_record;
                TextView textprintdefaultgen_system_charge;
                TextView textprintdefaulttrans_system_chg;
                TextView textprintdefaultsystem_loss_chg;
                TextView textprintdefaultdistr_system_chg;
                TextView textprintdefaultsupply_system_chg;
                TextView textprintdefaultsupply_retail_chg;
                TextView textprintdefaultmeter_system_chg;
                TextView textprintdefaultmeter_retail_chg;
                TextView textprintdefaultrsfc;
                TextView textprintdefaultlife_line_subsidy;
                TextView textprintdefaultppa_refund;
                TextView textprintdefaulticcs_adjustment;
                TextView textprintdefaultgeneration_vat;
                TextView textprintdefaulttransmission_vat;
                TextView textprintdefaultsystem_loss_vat;
                TextView textprintdefaultdistribution_vat;
                TextView textprintdefaultothers_vat;
                TextView textprintdefaultsenior_citizen_subsidy;
                TextView textprintdefaultfit_all;
                TextView textprintdefaultmissionary_elec_spug;
                TextView textprintdefaultenvir_charge;
                TextView textprintdefaultstranded_contract_cost;
                TextView textprintdefaultnpc_scc_debt;
                public Holder()
                {

                }
        }
}
```

This is the Error

```
Process: com.vicjames.finalmeterreader, PID: 26494
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.vicjames.finalmeterreader.ui.tools.ToolsFragment.getdefaultvaluestoprint()' on a null object reference
        at com.vicjames.finalmeterreader.ui.home.HomeFragment$4.onClick(HomeFragment.java:119)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6412)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25341)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:202)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6962)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:528)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:888)
```

I've been searching for days but I can't find a solution. The only thing I know now is that fragments can't communicate directly but I still don't know how to fix this.Need help:(

Comment: If both fragments are in the same container then `findFragmentById(R.id.nav_toolsx)` return the current fragment which is FragmentB.

Comment: Use observer pattern through activity to achieve this. Hope this will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58535588/2637449

Comment: They are in a different container

Comment: Try to do through the help of Activity. Check my above link. Hope this will help you

Comment: **@Md.Asaduzzaman** Where should I create the Interface, sorry, newbie here

Comment: Create in separate file

Comment: I can't make it work:(((

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: the interface isn't working:(

Comment: do you want me to debug your code?

Comment: yes, please:( I'm running out of ideas