# Passing Data Between Fragments from a BaseAdapter override class

Tags: interface, android-fragments, argument-passing, baseadapter

Ik im probably not going about this the best way , but I have no idea how to go about this the right way given my current setup . Pretty much I have a fragment tabhost that has just about all my content including a newsfeed, from the newsfeed users can click another users picture to open their profile. Up until now I was taking the easy way out and just using a intent which opened a whole new instance of the tabhost and all the fragments, i sent the  profile id over via a intent extra and my problem was solved, but ive since learned this isnt a great solution . So ive been trying to fix up my app by taking the advice on this thread:

[Communication between Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858619/communication-between-fragments)

my problem is bc my onClick listeners for the profile images is in my LazyAdapter class which extends BaseAdapter, whats the best way to switch out the fragments and pass over the proper profile id  to the new fragment given my situation?

```
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;





public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

    public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        TextView name = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.name); // title
        TextView message = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.message); // artist name
        TextView created = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.created); // duration
        SmartImageView thumb_image = (SmartImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image);



        HashMap<String, String> update = new HashMap<String, String>();
        update = data.get(position); 

        // Setting all values in listview
        name.setText(update.get("name"));
        message.setText(update.get("message"));
        created.setText(update.get("created"));
        thumb_image.setImageUrl(update.get("thumb_img"));
        name.setOnClickListener(new myOnClickListener(position));
        thumb_image.setOnClickListener(new myOnClickListener(position));
        return vi;
    }

    public class myOnClickListener implements OnClickListener{
        private int position;
        private String clicked_uid;
        public myOnClickListener(int position){
            this.position=position;
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            HashMap<String, String> update = new HashMap<String, String>();
            update = data.get(position); 
            Log.i("Update Position:", update.toString());
            clicked_uid=update.get("uid");
            Log.d("Clicked UID:", clicked_uid+"");
            Intent i = new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext() , TabHostFragmentActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("profile_uid", clicked_uid);
            activity.startActivity(i);
            activity.finish();

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can we achieved by a very simple method.

 ref:[Answered Here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22265378/how-to-call-a-fragment-from-baseadapter-class-android/24890123#24890123