# How to call a fragment from BaseAdapter Class Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

I want to call a Fragement from my BaseAdapter Class. In this class I have button on click of which I want to call the new fragment, but I am not able to get this. I have to pass values from the click of the button to the fragment.

**BaseAdapter Class**

```
public class StatusAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    public StatusAdapter(Activity a,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data = d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        if (convertView == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.approval_selftrip_inner, null);
        TextView approved_by = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.approved_by);
        TextView status = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.status);
        TextView trip = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.trip);
        Button view_log = (Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.view_log);

        HashMap<String, String> list = new HashMap<String, String>();
        list = data.get(position);
        approved_by.setText(list.get("first_id"));
        status.setText(list.get("status"));
        trip.setText(list.get("trip"));
        view_log.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //Here i want to call my fragment 

            }
        });
        return vi;
    }
}
```

**Fragement**

```
public class Log extends Fragment {
    Context context ;
    View rootView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        context = getActivity();

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_log,
                container, false);
        return rootView;
    }


}
```

I want to call this Fragment from the BaseAdapter Class on click of `view_log`.Please help me how can we do this

After **Martin Cazares** I have done this

In **Activity**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    context = getActivity();
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main,
                container, false);
        mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Recived", 
                           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                ApprovalLog fragment2 = new ApprovalLog();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                        .beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment2);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        };
        return rootView;
    }
```

In The **AdapterClass**

```
view_approvallog.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CommonUtils.showAlert("Test in Adapter", activity);
                activity.registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                        "start.fragment.action"));

            }
        });
```

Comment: what is R.id.content_frame  in 

fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment2);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use this.

```
public void onClick(View view) {
 LogFrag fragment2 = new LogFrag();
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
 fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment1, fragment2);
 fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: i am getting this exception The method getFragmentManager() is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}

Comment: @PoojaDubey : have u tried `activity.getFragmentManager();` ? or you need Activity Context to access `getFragmentManager();` on Button Click

Comment: Change this FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();to FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getFragmentManager();

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from android.app.FragmentManager to android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager

Comment: what is your minimum SDK??

Comment: Is imported as android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager ??

Comment: It is also better to call Fragment on ItemCLick of ListView.

Comment: Change android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager  to android.app.FragmentManager

Comment: The method replace(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, Log)

Comment: @PoojaDubey u need to use getSupportFragmentManager() since u r calling inside base adapter class.

Answer (score 16):

Honestly if you have to call your fragment from a BaseAdapter something is terribly wrong with your application's architecture, you are tightly coupling components and Spaghetti Code will be a problem soon, if you want to keep it clean, make a listener or send a broadcast from it, and call your fragment from your activity as you usually do, the point is to keep components doing the job they are intended for and not having all in one single class, that's a terrible thing to do and code becomes less legible.

As explained a simple approach to decouple things in android is by sending broadcast messages, so this is one way of doing it:

```
 view_log.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Here i want to call my fragment
            //You need to pass a reference of the context to your adapter...
            context.sendBroadcast(new Intent("start.fragment.action"))

        }
    });
```

Now in your activity all you have to do is register a BroadcastReceiver with the "start.fragment.action" and that's it inside of it just call your fragment:

```
//In your activity...
context.registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("start.fragment.action"))
.
.
.   
BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    //This piece of code will be executed when you click on your item
            // Call your fragment...
        }
    };
```

Do not forget to unregister when done, and if you need to pass some parameters to the fragment you can use extras in the intent when sending the broadcast message...

> NOTE: [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) would be better to use now.

Regards!

Comment: can u suggest me how can we implement this.i don't have much exp please suggest me the better way

Comment: Totally agree with your answer. Adapter is pattern used for converting one interface to another (in this case - list of models into list of views), it shouldn't be responsible for handling user interaction inside rows.

Comment: agree but can you post sample code for me how could i do the changes

Comment: @Martin Cazares can u post sample code how could we do this

Comment: you just call context.unregisterReceiver(BroadcastReceiver receiver), you need to read a good android book...

Comment: @PoojaDubey: by calling `unregisterReceiver` method you can unregister receiver

Comment: @MartinCazares see i have updated my code .but this is not working fine for me it is not calling the fragment even i am not getting the Toast .Please suggest me where i have done wrong

Comment: you are registering when the item is being clicked, you must be sendBroadcast when clicked as shown in my edit, by the time you sendBroadcast, the broadcast must be already registered to be notified... move the register logic to the onCreateView if you want...

Comment: i am not getting you what i have did wrong in my code that i have posted in my edit please suggest me in that

Comment: read careful my previous comment, and please go read a tutorial about Broadcast Receivers in Android it will help you understand better...

Comment: User always LocalBroadcastManager to send and receive broadcast within  the single application. added in api level 20. But can be use in below level through support v4 jar. 
Pros: this broadcast validate only in application Neither the out side of app. Andy broadcast out side the app will never receiver this.

Comment: Works great! And it is a very elegant solution, besides. I am reaching an already medium level of android, and this technique solves many entanglements I've been having when calling difficult functions  from difficult places.

Answer (score 11):

Use

```
((Activity) mContext).getFragmentManager();//use this

view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Fragment fragment = new CallThisFragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((Activity) mContext).getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_activity, fragment).commit();
        }
    });
```

Comment: If you are using `getSupportFragmentManager()` use:

    `((FragmentActivity) context)`

Answer (score 1):

```
FragmentManager manager = ((AppCompatActivity) 
context).getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = manager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, new AlbumFragment());
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way: 
  Do in Fragment

```
Adapter a = new Adapter(arg,Fragment.this);// or only this. This will pass the fragment object to the adapter.
```

and in Adapter

```
v.ckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {


            if(fragment!=null)
                fragment.ValidateList();// call any public method of the fragment
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse FragmentManager **xxx** object to Adpter Constructor,

```
**xxx**.beginTransaction().replace(your_container, new YourNewFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Answer (score -2):

Perfect way to call fragment from Custom Base Adapter

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.content_frame, new YourFragmentName())
        .addToBackStack("fragBack")).commit();
((Activity) context).setTitle("Title For Action Bar");`
```