# Fragment with a ListView calling another Fragment

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter, android-broadcast

I have an `Fragment` with a `ListView` from where i want to call another `Fragment`. In my `BaseAdapter` i want to register an `onClick` and open a `new Fragment` where i use a `ViewPager`. 
Is here `Broadcastreciver/sender` the right way to go? or can i just call the `new Fragment` in the onClick method?

If `Broadcastreciver` ist the way to go, i would appreciate it if you could help me with the Code. I have never used a `Broadcastreciver` before. What comes in the `onClick method` and what needs to be done in my `mainActivity`.

Thanks

Comment: You can go ahead with ViewPager no need of BroadcastReciever for that.

Comment: ok, so this wouldn't be any "bad" code if i call the viewPager fragment in my BaseAdapter and not go over my MainActivity? 
This is what i found: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22265433/4061645

Comment: ViewPager architecture is with fragments so its not an issue