# Register Broadcast receiver in Fragment PageViewer

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest

I have previously asked a question in Stack for this and this is a continuing one for it

Previous question

[Calling Fragment from inside the BaseAdapter class in PageViewer Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30206273/calling-fragment-from-inside-the-baseadapter-class-in-pageviewer-android)

Now I click on button .. it goes to register but can seem to call the Fragment .
I think I need to register .

How can I do it in manifest file for Fragment
Below is my code for Broadcast receiver called within Adapterclass

Code in Fragment class and this mBroadcastReceiver is passed to BaseAdapter class

```
 mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Recived", 
                               Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    FieldVisitFragment fieldvisitFragment = new FieldVisitFragment();
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                            .beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.tabcontent, fieldvisitFragment);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                }
```

Onclick of button within List from Adapter class

I have added the code inside the BaseAdapter class

```
visitImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Toast.makeText(con, "Visit Clicked ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                con.registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                        "start.fragment.action"));
            }
        });
```

For Registration in Manifest file

```
  <receiver android:name="what should I write here ???">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="start.fragment.action"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Changes done after seen in answer but still not working

Manifest file

```
<receiver android:name="companyname.appname.fragments.FragmentClassName$BroadT">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="start.fragment.action"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

BroadT class  which is defined inside Fragment class

```
public class FragmentClassName extends Fragment
```

The BroadT class

```
class BroadT extends BroadcastReceiver
      {
          @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Recived", 
                               Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    FieldVisitFragment fieldvisitFragment = new FieldVisitFragment();
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                            .beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.tabcontent, fieldvisitFragment);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                }
      }
```

My call in Base Adapter class

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Toast.makeText(con, "Visit Clicked ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                con.registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                        "start.fragment.action"));
            }
```

But my  `<receiver android:name="packagename.BroadT">` BroadT class does not seem to link to call the class

I feel I need to use NESTED FRAGMENTS Can Anyone help ?

Comment: First accept already asked question and then ask new question.

Comment: @MikeM. No. it's not.I am talking about OP's first question.

Comment: @MikeM. Now you get it my POINT....Hurry!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to register fragment into manifest

you can register receiver from fragment like this way

```
    private ScreenTimeOutReceiver mScreenTimeOutReceiver;

    mScreenTimeOutReceiver = new ScreenTimeOutReceiver();
    registerReceiver(mScreenTimeOutReceiver, filter);
```

Comment: I have a Broadcast receiver inside a fragment

Comment: than what?register receiver only

Comment: How can I register ... I have used below thing in Manifest file to register     <receiver android:name="what should I write here ">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="start.fragment.action"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Comment: Have made changes as seen... and have shown in code ... Kindly check